# I need any app or any website by the help of that i can easily download the mp3 or video songs or movie from Youtube.com

Tags: youtube

Looking for a app for ubuntu 14.04

I need a app to download the songs and video from  youtube.com.

Is there any way to get the sign of download on youtube while watching any favourite songs or videoes?

In my friends computer the download option comes on youtube while watching any movie or song on youtube.com,  he was using Windows7. But I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

By clicking on download, he was able to download that songs from youtube directly?

I need a best app or website in Ubuntu to download the songs from youtube.com

Comment: Any helpful answer will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox as your browser then there is an extension you can install.

Download YouTube Videos as MP4 what i use however for mp3 they also have,
Youtube MP3 Downloader using youtube.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide information of where to get it from, installation, and usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `youtube-dl` and a `youtube-dlg`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
sudo apt-get install youtube-dlg
```

to download videos and mp3 via GUI or command line.

The PPA is updated more frequently so that one is the preferred source.

[image]

[image]

[image]

More details [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/video-downloader-youtube-dl-gets.html?m=1) and [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/multi-platform-youtube-dl-gui-youtube.html).

Comment: No need to add a PPA, it's in universe.

Comment: Yes, @the_Seppi is correct. It is in universe but the PPA mentioned by A.B. is updated more frequently so that one is the preferred source.

Comment: @the_Seppi sure, but the version is out dated.